# Select data based on combinations of values present in one table but not in another

Tags: sql

From 2 SQL Relational tables below. I want to Display people who watched videos but did not pay on each day using T-SQL OR MYSQL

Payment table as shown below: This table contains all the payment records on a date and member level. This is for members who make a payment on each day. A sample data looks like this:

```
Date    memID   Amount
1/5     Abc      $30
1/10    def      $50
1/27    hij      $15
```

User Table: This table contains all the active records on a date and member level. This is for member who visit abcvideo.com site on each day. A sample data looks like this:

```
Date    memID
1/1      Abc
1/5      Abc
1/5      Bac
1/10     Abc
1/10     def
1/15     Bac
```

I came up with this really big code for a such a small logic as I couldn't get my head around it.

```
SELECT Date, memberID
FROM User 
WHERE Date NOT IN (SELECT Date FROM Payment )
UNION 
SELECT Date,memberID
FROM User
WHERE memberID NOT IN (SELECT memberID FROM Payment)
UNION
SELECT Date, memberID
FROM User
WHERE Date IN (SELECT Date from Payment where user.memberID <> payment.memberID)
```

Looking a simpler and better logic.

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your pay is per day then you probably look for something like this

```
select *
from user u
where not exists(
  select 1
  from payment p
  where u.memId = p.memId and 
        u.Date = p.Date
)
```

Sidenote: it is not a good idea to assign names to tables and attributes that are keywords (`user` and `Date`).

Comment: thanks, that worked. Seems like a very simple and logical code too. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Date, memberID
FROM User 
WHERE (Date NOT IN (SELECT Date FROM Payment )) 
   OR (memberID NOT IN (SELECT memberID FROM Payment)) 
   OR (Date IN (SELECT Date from Payment where user.memberID <> payment.memberID))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
SELECT u.memid, u.date_col
FROM user_table u
LEFT JOIN payment p
ON p.date_col = u.date_col AND p.memid = u.memid
WHERE p.date_col IS NULL
ORDER BY u.memid, u.date_col;
```